# How to use default and custom marker on same Google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to show default and custom marker on the same map in android ,If only default markers are available the code is working properly but if i add custom markers and click on default marker it gives error. i have done the code using InfoWindowAdapter.

here's my InfoWindowAdater

```
     public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
{
    private final View v;


    public MarkerInfoWindowAdapter()
    {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_item, null);

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {


            MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);

            LinearLayout LayoutItem1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LayoutItem1);
            LinearLayout LayoutItem2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LayoutItem2);
            LinearLayout LayoutItem3 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LayoutItem3);

            ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.IV_UserImg);
            ImageView markerIcon1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.IV_UserImg1);
            ImageView markerIcon2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.IV_UserImg2);

            TextView markerLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_UserName);
            TextView markerLabel1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_UserName1);
            TextView markerLabel2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_UserName2);


            if (ResultArray.length() == 1) {

                markerIcon.setImageBitmap(myMarker.getmProfilePic());
                markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmName());
                LayoutItem1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.e("VALUE", "1");

            }
            if (ResultArray.length() == 2) {

                markerIcon.setImageBitmap(myMarker.getmProfilePic());
                markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmName());
                LayoutItem1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                markerIcon1.setImageBitmap(myMarker.getmProfilePic1());
                markerLabel1.setText(myMarker.getmName1());
                LayoutItem2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.e("VALUE", "2");

            }
            if (ResultArray.length() == 3) {

                markerIcon.setImageBitmap(myMarker.getmProfilePic());
                markerLabel.setText(myMarker.getmName());
                LayoutItem1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                markerIcon1.setImageBitmap(myMarker.getmProfilePic1());
                markerLabel1.setText(myMarker.getmName1());
                LayoutItem2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                markerIcon2.setImageBitmap(myMarker.getmProfilePic2());
                markerLabel2.setText(myMarker.getmName2());
                LayoutItem3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.e("VALUE", "3");

            }

            return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: Which error you got?? Please post here

Comment: Post your logcat as well.

Comment: Here is the error :  

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap com.Model.MyMarker.getmProfilePic()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.MainActivity$MarkerInfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents(MainActivity.java:894)

Comment: from logout you have provided seems you myMarker is null. Make sure MyMarker myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);  is giving you a MyMarker instance

Comment: First I am adding default markers then on a button click I am adding a custom marker , So can you tell what i am doing wrong ..or can you tell me how it is done properly

Comment: You are pointing to an object that does not exist- your custom marker. Try logging if your custom marker was instantiated before you made a call to it. Try to check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347719/google-map-custom-marker-info-window-setting-error) also, it might give you an idea.